# dynamic checkbox doesn't bind properly with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

dynamic checkbox doesn't bind properly with ng-model

http://plnkr.co/edit/ECFxC8qs2qOpfauPvr0u

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

json = [{"name":"john"},{"name":"Amy"}];

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = false;
  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      this is static checkbox <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked1"/>
<br>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/></td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    check1 : {{checked1}} check2 : {{checked}} 
  </body>

</html>
```

The second checkbox which it's within the ng-repeat doesn't return true when u click on the checkbox?

Comment: is this basically a more fleshed out version of the question you already asked? I already addressed this issue in that question.  because you are using a **primitive** instead of an **object**, it is hidden by `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define property for each object, which you are going to bind with checkbox. 
`json = [{"name":"john",value:"false"},{"name":"Amy",value:"false"}];`

Like above, you have to add `value` parameter to each object. And then bind that with checkbox this way
`<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.value"/></td>`
And this is how you use those values, as data is an array of objects 
`{{data[0].value}} check2 : {{data[1].value}}`
Ans as whole,This is how it is done.Run snippet and see.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

json = [{"name":"john",value:"false"},{"name":"Amy",value:"false"}];

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.checked = false;
  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.value"/></td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        
      </tr>
    </table>
    check1 : {{data[0].value}} check2 : {{data[1].value}} 
  </body>
```

Comment: I want to catch if checked or not, not retrieving the json's value.

Comment: this `value` is actually attached to your object. Which tells whether checked or not. You need some object to bind to checkbox tag. You can see it.

Comment: You are passing json to $scope.data, and $scope.data objects are is bind to checkbox through `value`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not exactly sure how the angular mechanism works here but from what I understand, within an ng-repeat directive you get a new scope so if you want to use a scope variable inside an ng-repeat directive, you need to make sure that $parent.varName format is used. Checkout the following modification that seems to do what you're trying to achieve.

PS: Sorry the answer doesn't provide much technical insight.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

json = [{"name":"john"},{"name":"Amy"}];

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checked = false;
  $scope.data = json;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      this is static checkbox <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked1"/>
<br>

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checked"/></td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    check1 : {{checked1}} check2 : {{checked}} 
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: this work but it checked all of the checkbox, any fix for that?

Comment: I understand and trust that you're right @wickY26 but downvoting my answer isn't really fair since it achieves what OP wanted to know, right? Also, please post the correct/common way to do it for the sake of both of us and the googlers? thanks.

Comment: @AliceXu Well, you're using the same model for both checkboxes so it's normal that it checks both of the inputs. This is the expected result with your approach.